# Doubt on a simple proof exercise about operators between normed spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, operator-theory

**Exercise.** Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from a normed space $X$ onto a normed space $Y$. Show that if there is a constant $c>0$ such that

$$ \|Tx\| \geqslant c\|x\|, \quad \forall x \in X, $$

then $T$ admits inverse, $T^{-1}$, and it is bounded.

**My attempt.** To see that $T$ admits inverse, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{N}(T) = \{0_X\},$ where $\mathcal N(T)$ stands for the null space of $T$ (or kernell, depending on the literature). The inclusion $\{0_X\} \subset \mathcal N(T)$ is obvious since $T(0_X) = 0_Y,$ in every scenario. On the other hand, let $x \in X$ be an arbitrary element such that $\mathcal x \in \mathcal N(T),$ i.e., $T(x) = 0_Y.$ Replacing this in the inequality from the **exercise**, it follows that

$$ \|T(x)\| = 0 \geqslant c\|x\| \Leftrightarrow \|x\| \leqslant 0. $$

By properties of the norm, one knows that $\|x\| \geqslant 0,$ and so, it comes that $\|x\| = 0.$ Again by properties of the norm, it follows that $x = 0_X$, proving that $\mathcal N(T) \subset \{0_X\}.$ Thus, $T$ admits inverse.

Now, we must prove that $T^{-1}$ is bounded. Fix an arbitrary $y \in Y.$ Since $T$ is surjective, we can guarantee that there is some $x \in X$ such that $T(x) = y$ (or equivalently, $T^{-1}(y) = x.$ In particular, this element $x \in X$ satisfies the inequality provided by hypothesis in the exercise. Thus,

$$ \|Tx\| \geqslant c\|x\| \Leftrightarrow \|y\| \geqslant c\|T^{-1}y\| \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{c}\|y\| \geqslant \|T^{-1}y\|. $$
Since $\frac{1}{c} > 0$ and our choice of $y$ was arbitrary, we might conclude that
$$ \| T^{-1}y \|  \leqslant \frac{1}{c}\|y\|, \quad \forall y \in Y,$$
i.e., $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

**My concerns.** I can't say where my proof is wrong (if it is) but at the same time I have a (REALLY) weird feeling: I never used the fact that $T$ is bounded, and I also enver used the fact that $T$ is linear during the whole proof. Can someone explain me what is the necessity of this conditions in the **exercise.** ?

Comment: Well when you write  $T(0)=0$ you are assuming that the operator is linear, aren't you?

Comment: @G.Gare How so? I thought that was true for any operator between normed spaces, independently of linearity

Comment: @roro Apostol's Calculus, Vol 2, Theorem 2.10:

Comment: "Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation in $L(V,W)$. Then the following statements are equivalent: 1. $T$ is one-to-one on $V$. 2. T is invertible and its inverse $T^{-1}$; $T(V) \to V$ is linear. 3. For all x in V, T(x) =0 implies x =0"

Comment: I proved that part of that theorem in my resolution, I never used it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use boundedness. In fact, your proof works for linear $T$ without boundedness.

As an example,
consider the following operator $T$, as a linear map from $c_{00}$ to $c_{00}$, where $c_{00}$ is the space of finite sequences (supplied with any $l^p$-norm):
$$
T(x) = (x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, \dots).
$$
This $T$ is linear from $c_{00}$ to $c_{00}$, bijective, but unbounded. It satisfies your inequality with $c=1$,
and $T^{-1}$ is linear and bounded, it is given by
$$
T^{-1}(x) = (x_1, x_2/2, x_3/3, \dots).
$$